# Getting form data on submit?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

When my form is submitted I wish to get an input value:

```
<input type="text" id="name">
```

I know I can use form input bindings to update the values to a variable, but how can I just do this on submit. I currently have:

```
<form v-on:submit.prevent="getFormValues">
```

But how can I get the value inside of the getFormValues method?

Also, side question, is there any benefit to doing it on submit rather than updating variable when user enters the data via binding?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You should use model binding, especially here as mentioned by Schlangguru in his response.

However, there are other techniques that you can use, like normal Javascript or references. But I really don't see why you would want to do that instead of model binding, it makes no sense to me:

```
<div id="app">
  <form>
    <input type="text" ref="my_input">
    <button @click.prevent="getFormValues()">Get values</button>
  </form>
  Output: {{ output }}
</div>
```

As you see, I put `ref="my_input"` to get the input DOM element:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    output: ''
  },
  methods: {
    getFormValues () {
      this.output = this.$refs.my_input.value
    }
  }
})
```

I made a small jsFiddle if you want to try it out: https://jsfiddle.net/sh70oe4n/

**But once again, my response is far from something you could call "good practice"**

Comment: Thanks for advising about good practice,  looks like I should just follow the model binding technique.

Comment: This worked for me, but It seems like you can't hard code two checkboxes?

Answer (score 63):

The form `submit` action emits a [`submit` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/submit), which provides you with the event target, among other things.

The submit event's target is an HTMLFormElement, which has an elements property. See [this MDN link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/elements) for how to iterate over, or access specific elements by name or index.

If you add a `name` property to your input, you can access the field like this in your form submit handler:

```
<form @submit.prevent="getFormValues">
  <input type="text" name="name">
</form>

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    name: ''
  },
  methods: {
    getFormValues (submitEvent) {
      this.name = submitEvent.target.elements.name.value
    }
  }
}
```

As to why you'd want to do this: HTML forms already provide helpful logic like disabling the `submit` action when a form is not valid, which I prefer not to re-implement in Javascript. So, if I find myself generating a list of items that require a small amount of input before performing an action (like selecting the number of items you'd like to add to a cart), I can put a form in each item, use the native form validation, and then grab the value off of the target form coming in from the submit action.

Comment: I think this approach also makes sense when you collect the values and send them to a remote point with ajax, too. Why include another v-model? Seems unnecessary

Comment: Also, is there anyway to get all input values from a mult-field form without going through  - submitEvent.target.elements.name.value, submitEvent.target.elements.age.value, submitEvent.target.elements.gender.value etc. etc. Is there any shorthand to get all values submitted by the form?

Comment: @ΛBHINΛV using [this MDN example as a guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/elements#Accessing_form_controls), you can iterate over all of the form elements using a loop: `for(let element of submitEvent.target.elements) {  // do something with element.value }`

Answer (score 18):

You have to define a model for your input.
`<input type="text" id="name" v-model="name">`

Then you you can access the value with
`this.name` inside your `getFormValues` method.

This is at least how they do it in the official TodoMVC example: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/examples/todomvc.html (See `v-model="newTodo"` in HTML and `addTodo()` in JS)

Answer (score 1):

Please see below for sample solution, I combined the use of `v-model` and "submitEvent" i.e. `<input type="submit" value="Submit">`. Used submitEvent to benefit from the built in form validation.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
        </head>
    <body>
      <div id="app">
        <form  @submit.prevent="getFormValues">
           <div class="form-group">
              <input type="email" class="form-control form-control-user"                                            
              v-model="exampleInputEmail"                                
              placeholder="Enter Email Address...">
           </div>
           <div class="form-group">
              <input type="password" class="form-control"
              v-model="exampleInputPassword" placeholder="Password">   </div>
              <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
      </div>
      <script>
            const vm = new Vue({
                    el: '#app',
                    methods: {
                        getFormValues (submitEvent) {
                        alert("Email: "+this.exampleInputEmail+" "+"Password: "+this.exampleInputPassword);
                        }
                    }
            }); 
        </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answers suggest assembling your json POST body from input or model values, one by one. This is fine, but you also have the option of **grabbing the whole FormData of your form and whopping it off to the server in one hit**. The following working example uses Vue 3 with Axios, typescript, the composition API and setup, but the same trick will work anywhere.

I like this method because there's less handling. If you're old skool, you can specify the endpoint and the encoding type directly on the form tag.

You'll note that we grab the form from the submit event, so there's no ref, and no document.getElementById(), the horror.

I've left the console.log() there to show that you need the spread operator to see what's inside your FormData before you send it.

```
<template>
    <form @submit.prevent="formOnSubmit">
        <input type="file" name="aGrid" />
        <input type="text" name="aMessage" />
        <input type="submit" />
    </form>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import axiosClient from '../../stores/http-common';

const formOnSubmit = (event: SubmitEvent) => {
    const formData = new FormData(event.target as HTMLFormElement);
    console.log({...formData});
    axiosClient.post(`api/my-endpoint`, formData, {
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
        }
    })
}
</script>
```

Comment: `console.log({...formData})` sadly doesn't work. You should be using `console.log(Object.fromEntries(formData))`