# Update component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am missunderstanding how to update a component.
So, here is the HTML :

```
<div id="app">

  <form v-on:submit="submitForm">
    <input type="text" id="txtSearch">
    <input type="submit" value="go">
  </form>

  <br><br>

  <user></user>

</div>
```

And the JS :

```
let userComponent = {
    template: 'your name is : {{name}}<br>You are {{age}}'
    };

let vueApp = new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  components: {'user': userComponent},

  methods: {
    submitForm: function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      let val = document.getElementById('txtSearch').value;
      alert('submitted : ' + val);
      // normally i do a search here : let result = mySearch(val);
      // but let's do the job with this :
      let result = {name: 'John', age: 27};
      // so now, how to modify the <user> with this data result ?
      }
  }
});
```

So, my aim is to create a  template, and of course update his data.
How to do this ?
I created a jsfiddle for testing : https://jsfiddle.net/4w0kh30t/1/
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your question is very similar to this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42694457/getting-form-data-on-submit). You could do it like in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/4w0kh30t/4/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need a  *data* for your vue instance to make your data reactive.
So add to your vueApp a data, like so:

```
let vueApp = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
     person: {
         name: '',
         age: 0,
     }
  }
  components: {'user': userComponent},
  methods: {
    submitForm: function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      let val = document.getElementById('txtSearch').value;
      alert('submitted : ' + val);
      // normally i do a search here : let result = mySearch(val);
      // but let's do the job with this :
      let result = {name: 'John', age: 27};
      // so now, how to modify the <user> with this data result ?
      }
  }
});
```

Now to make changes you need to use `this.person = something`, which womething will be your result in the submit event method, like this:

```
submitForm: function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      let val = document.getElementById('txtSearch').value;
      alert('submitted : ' + val);
      // normally i do a search here : let result = mySearch(val);
      // but let's do the job with this :
      let result = {name: 'John', age: 27};
      this.person = result
    }
 }
```

Now, to your component react to changes it must receive data through **properties or props**. Changing component to this:

```
let userComponent = {
    props: ['user'],
    template: 'your name is : {{name}}<br>You are {{age}}'
};
```

In the end, you need to pass **person** to the component in the template of vue instance:

```
<user :user="person"></user>
```

The result is here:

https://jsfiddle.net/jhs7ffch/1/