# Vue - using method/s to add together two inputs and save into data

Tags: vue.js

I am playing around with a component in Vue.  I am trying to have two input boxes.  Each box you can input an integer and save that integer to a data property using a button.  Then I want to use another button to add the two integers saved in data together and output it as text interpolation.  I can't seem to crack this or find the answer anywhere.  I am quite new to programming and Vue in general.

```
<template>

<template>
<!-- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42694457/getting-form-data-on-submit -->
<div>
  <div>
  <form @submit.prevent="getFormValues" class="inputPad">
  <input type="text" name="name">
  <button>Save Amount</button>
  </form>
  <form @submit.prevent="getFormValues2" class="inputPad">
  <input type="text" name="name">
  <button>Save Amount</button>
  </form>

  </div>
  <div>
  {{ totalBox1 }}<br>
  {{ totalBox2 }}<br>
  <p>Calculate Total</p>
  <button @submit="addTogether">Calculate Total</button>
  {{ total }}
  </div>

</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Calculate",
  data() {
    return {
      total: "0",
      totalBox1: "0",
      totalBox2: "0"
    };
  },
  methods: {
    getFormValues(submitEvent1) {
      this.totalBox1 = submitEvent1.target.elements.name.value;
    },
    getFormValues2(submitEvent) {
      this.totalBox2 = submitEvent.target.elements.name.value;
    }
  },
  computed: {}
};
</script>

<!-- Add "scoped" attribute to limit CSS to this component only -->
<style scoped>
.inputPad {
  padding: 10px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Hi Andrew. Welcome to SO. You should checkout the Vue documentation about [form-binding](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html). The `v-model` attribute might be exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: Hi @ferdynator, thanks for the reply.  V-bind may be suitable however the issue I have is assigning a particular value to a data property so that it is 'saved' and not changed dynamically?

Comment: You mean the values should only change on button clicked? You can use the `@click` attribute to call a `method` on a button-click.

Comment: Thanks again @ferdynator.  I understand that, however I am then having issues within the method in how to assign the argument and pass it to a data property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As requested. All you have to do is create 2 inputs and link them to a date, and calculate them according to the code below.

```
<div id="app">
<input v-model.number="value1" type="number"/>
<button v-on:click="val1">Save Amount</button>
<input v-model.number="value2" type="number"/>
<button v-on:click="val2">Save Amount</button>
<button @click="valueTotal">Total</button>
Total: {{total}}
</div>


new Vue({
el: '#app',
methods: {
val1 () {
    this.totalBox1 = this.value1
},
val2 () {
    this.totalBox2 = this.value2
},
valueTotal () {
    this.total = this.totalBox1 + this.totalBox2
}
},
data: {
totalBox1: '',
totalBox2: '',
value1: 0,
value2: 0,
total: ''
}
})
```

Example:
https://jsfiddle.net/hamiltongabriel/ke8w9czy/

Comment: Thankyou this is exactly what I was trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

No need for methods:

```
<template>
<div>
  <input type="text" v-model="item1"><br>
  <input type="text" v-model="item2">
  <p>Total</p>
  {{ total }}
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Calculate",
  data() {
    return {
      item1: 0,
      item2: 0
    }
  },
  computed: {
    total () {
      return this.item1 + this.item2
    }
  }
}
</scrip>
```

Comment: No, he have no idea what he need. And you? Do you really use two almost identical methods for one functionality?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Vladislav.  You are correct, I do have no idea what I need, and after many hours of my own frustrating research I thought I would ask my first question on stackoverflow :)

Comment: I'm sorry @Andrew but there is really no need to use anything else than v-model with inputs. Even you are trying to save values from inputs outside the application. Property v-model directly, or with getter and setter is all you need. Just stay strong and continue with JS and Vue.

Comment: Thankyou @Vladislav.  Through asking this question I have already learnt that v-model with inputs is the best way so I have learnt a lot already; so thankyou. I am very determined to get better and then I can hopefully help others.

Answer (score 0):

here is how to it step by step with buttons, I showcased two way of calculating the total: with and without a method

```
<template>
  <div>

    <input type="text" v-model="input1">
    <input type="text" v-model="input2">

    <button @click="value1 = input1">save value 1</button>
    <button @click="value2 = input2">save value 2</button>

    <button @click="calculateTotal()">calculate total</button>
    <button @click="total = value1 + value2">calculate total</button>

    total : {{ total }}

  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Calculate",
  data() {
    return {
      input1: 0,
      input2: 0,
      value1: 0,
      value2: 0,
      total: 0,
    };
  },
  methods:{
    calculateTotal(){
      this.total = this.input1 + this.input2;
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

you probably don't want all the intermediate button click, so you could do it using directly the value bounded to the inputs:

```
<template>
  <div>

    <input type="text" v-model="value1">
    <input type="text" v-model="value2">

    <button @click="total = value1 + value2">calculate total</button>

    total : {{ total }}

  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Calculate",
  data() {
    return {
      value1: 0,
      value2: 0,
      total: 0,
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks @Mathieu I appreciate your time to answer this. This is pretty much what I was looking for however the values are being added together like a string rather than a mathematic function.  I will fiddle with this and see what I come up with.  Again many thanks and if I could upvote I would but my account is too new.

Comment: @Andrew maybe with type="number" on the inputs